# Why is this function can only be invoked by setInterval?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Time</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var attime;
  function clock(){
    var time=new Date();          
    attime = time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes() + ':' +time.getSeconds();

    document.getElementById("clock").value = attime;
  }
  clock();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="clock" size="50"  />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is above, but it won't work and throws me an error unless I replace the `clock()` to `setInterval(clock, 1000)`. It seems ridiculous, why can't a function be called directly?

Comment: It can if you call it after the page has loaded: `window.onload=function() { clock(); }` - your code is now accessing the input field before it exists

Comment: Because you call it before the document is ready.

Comment: Thanks you guys, I have more clear knowledge on this problem now.